# Why is a p:panelGrid's p:row's rendered attribute ignored and not ignored in identical p:dialogs when ui:included?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

I have an `index.xhtml`

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>Project1</title>
        <script name="jquery/jquery.js" library="primefaces"></script>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <ui:composition template="template.xhtml">
            <ui:define name="content">
                <h:form id="mainForm">
                    <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/includes/offer.xhtml">
                    </ui:include>
                    <p:messages/>
                </h:form>
            </ui:define>
        </ui:composition>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

using `template.xhtml`

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <ui:insert name="content"/>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

and including `/WEB-INF/includes/offer.xhtml`

```
<ui:composition>
    <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/dialogs/offerdialog.xhtml">
    </ui:include>
    <p:commandButton value="Dialog 1 (doesn't repond to mode change)"
            onsuccess="PF('myDialogVar1').show();">
    </p:commandButton>
    <p:commandButton value="Dialog 2 (does respond to mode change)"
            onsuccess="PF('myDialogVar').show();">
    </p:commandButton>
</ui:composition>
```

including `/WEB-INF/dialogs/offerdialog.xhtml`

```
<ui:composition>
    <p:dialog id="myDialog1" widgetVar="myDialogVar1" modal="true">
        <h:form>
            <h:panelGroup>
                <p:outputLabel value="Edit mode:"/>
                <p:selectOneButton value="#{offers.creationMode}">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{offers.creationModes}"/>
                    <p:ajax update="@form"/>
                </p:selectOneButton>
            </h:panelGroup>
            <p:panelGrid>
                <p:row>
                    <p:column>
                        <p:outputLabel value="Row 1:"/>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column>
                        <p:inputText>
                            <p:ajax/>
                        </p:inputText>
                    </p:column>
                </p:row>
                <p:row rendered="#{offers.displayAdvancedModeComponents()}">
                    <p:column>
                        <p:outputLabel value="Row 2:"/>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column>
                        <p:inputText>
                            <p:ajax/>
                        </p:inputText>
                    </p:column>
                </p:row>
            </p:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </p:dialog>
    <p:dialog id="myDialog" widgetVar="myDialogVar" modal="true">
        <h:form>
            <h:panelGroup>
                <p:outputLabel value="Edit mode:"/>
                <p:selectOneButton value="#{offers.creationMode}">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{offers.creationModes}"/>
                    <p:ajax update="@form"/>
                </p:selectOneButton>
            </h:panelGroup>
            <p:panelGrid>
                <p:row>
                    <p:column>
                        <p:outputLabel value="Row 1:"/>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column>
                        <p:inputText>
                            <p:ajax/>
                        </p:inputText>
                    </p:column>
                </p:row>
                <p:row rendered="#{offers.displayAdvancedModeComponents()}">
                    <p:column>
                        <p:outputLabel value="Row 2:"/>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column>
                        <p:inputText>
                            <p:ajax/>
                        </p:inputText>
                    </p:column>
                </p:row>
            </p:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </p:dialog>
</ui:composition>
```

The first dialog `myDialog` does not respond to changes of the creation mode (`BASIC` and `ADVANCED`) whereas the second identical `myDialog` does. The first one should respond as well like it does when everything is declared in `index.xhtml` without using the template.

The dialogs are identical in order to show that the issue occuring for the first dialog and not for the second doesn't have anything to do with the structure of the dialog. The example doesn't have any function except illustrating the unexpected behavior (`p:inputText` isn't bound to backing bean values, etc.).

MCVE is at https://github.com/krichter722/primefaces-datatable-row-not-updated.

I'm using Primefaces 6.1.

Comment: I can't test it right now, but I believe this is one of the "strange things" when working with dialogs. Try to use `appendTo="@(body)"` to make sure both dialogs are attached to the html-body rather than beeing "inplace". If that helps, try to move your dialog implementation "closer" to the body in order to avoid the `appendTo`-Attribute, which has several drawbacks.

Comment: @dognose Adding `appendTo="@(body)"` to the non-working dialog doesn't help. I'd really appreciate your help in this since you already seem to have an idea.

Comment: Then try to use `dynamic=true` on the dialogs. Why are you using 2 dialogs, if the content is equal equal? Another thing to try: You have now 2 Forms working with the same-Attribute `creationMode` - Depending on how primefaces designed the `changeEventListener`-Subscription, the second form might overwrite the first handlers registration, hence the dialog created second (dom-wise) works, first one not. (try it with `offer.creationMode1` and `offer.creationMode2`)

Comment: I also remember, that there was an issue within primefaces, if one id (or widget var, can't temember exactly) is a substring of another (`MyDialogVar` and `MyDialogVar1`) - try two distinct names as well (`MyDialogVar1` and `MyDialogVar2`). IIRC at one point primefaces uses something like `startsWith()` to find a component, which then is ambigious, always resulting in the "longer" Var name.

Comment: Did you try the suggested workaround by @dognose?

Comment: Great idea to have the code related to your question on Github, by the way!

Comment: @Robert I don't have the time to look into this now. I might have worked around the issue meanwhile or I might have fixed it (like I did fix some other issues in the same project with the following) by validating the HTML generated by the JSF implementation in the W3C XHTML validator. I had some trouble with nested forms and dialog which were far from obvious at the time. I try to get back at you and this question, but probably not the next days.